# How to improve SELECT statements with multiple sub-queries

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, subquery

How can I better improve the following SQL statements? I have tried using EXCEPT but it does not work. Any suggestions/advice are greatly welcome!

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM ( SELECT L_ORDERKEY, COUNT(*)
   FROM LINEITEM
   GROUP BY L_ORDERKEY
   HAVING COUNT(*) > (SELECT DISTINCT TSIZE
                      FROM LINEITEM) );


SELECT LINEITEM.L_ORDERKEY, LINEITEM.L_LINENUMBER
FROM LINEITEM JOIN PART
   ON LINEITEM.L_PARTKEY = PART.P_PARTKEY
WHERE PART.P_PARTKEY IN (46557,20193,19110,45690,45123)
   MINUS
      (SELECT LINEITEM.L_ORDERKEY, LINEITEM.L_LINENUMBER
       FROM LINEITEM JOIN PART
          ON LINEITEM.L_PARTKEY = PART.P_PARTKEY
       WHERE PART.P_PARTKEY IN (46557,20193,19110,45690,45123)
       MINUS
       SELECT LINEITEM.L_ORDERKEY, LINEITEM.L_LINENUMBER
       FROM LINEITEM JOIN SUPPLIER
          ON LINEITEM.L_SUPPKEY = SUPPLIER.S_SUPPKEY
       WHERE SUPPLIER.S_SUPPKEY IN (4567,2323,1987,2194,1111)
      );
```

Comment: Could you provide us some example of your table and exactly what you want?
I see you have two subqueries one within other, but the 3rd one are not within "( ... )"

Comment: @AurelianoGuedes Hi! My tables are very large hence the exclusion. I just wanted to see if there's any better way to approach these subqueries without having so many of it. Like an idea of how to do this better would be nice.

Comment: @AurelianoGuedes what do you mean by the "(...)" ? Is there something wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not exists` for the second query

```
   SELECT L.L_ORDERKEY, L.L_LINENUMBER
     FROM LINEITEM L
     JOIN PART P
       ON L.L_PARTKEY = P.P_PARTKEY
    WHERE P.P_PARTKEY IN (46557, 20193, 19110, 45690, 45123)
      AND NOT EXISTS
         (SELECT 0
            FROM SUPPLIER S
           WHERE S.S_SUPPKEY IN (4567, 2323, 1987, 2194, 1111)
             AND L.L_SUPPKEY = S.S_SUPPKEY );
```